# Ifelse statement for multiple, alternating conditions

Tags: r

My data involves an experiment with a dependent variable (DV) collected over several conditions and is structured as follows:

```
AnalysedData <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"),
                           Code = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                           Condition = c("Con", "Expr", "Plac", "Con", "Expr", "Plac", "Con", "Expr", "Plac"),
                           DV = c(26.07, 26.06, 26.05, 26.09, 26.04, 26.65, 26.64, 26.62, 26.63))
```

All the participants received the same conditions but completed two of the conditions in a randomised order - the control condition was always conducted first. Those who completed the experimental (`Expr`) condition as their second trial have a 1 for `Code` whilst those who completed the placebo (`Plac`) as their second trial have a 2 for `Code`.

I wish to include a new column `AnalysedData$Trial` whereby the order of trials, for each participant, are included. My preferred output would be:

```
AnalysedData <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"),
                           Code = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                           Condition = c("Con", "Expr", "Plac", "Con", "Expr", "Plac", "Con", "Expr", "Plac"),
                           DV = c(26.07, 26.06, 26.05, 26.09, 26.04, 26.65, 26.64, 26.62, 26.63),
                           Trial = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3))
```

The preferred output address that Harry completed the placebo condition second and the experimental condition third, giving him `c(1, 3, 2)`. In contrast, Bill and Paul both complete the experimental condition second and the placebo condition third, giving `c(1, 2, 3)`. As per above, this alternate sequence is indicated by `Code` equalling 1 for Bill and Paul, 2 for Harry.

I know that I can include a 1 to designate the first trial completed (`Con` for all participants) using the following:

```
AnalysedData$Trial <- ifelse(AnalysedData$Condition == "Con", 1, 0)
```

How do I complete the above for multiple conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of `ifelse`, `as.integer` (or `as.numeric`) and `factor` you can make use of the fact that factor variables are stored as integers with labels:

```
AnalysedData$Trial <- ifelse(AnalysedData$Code==1, 
                             as.integer(factor(AnalysedData$Condition, 
                                               levels = c("Con", "Expr", "Plac"))),
                             as.integer(factor(AnalysedData$Condition, 
                                               levels = c("Con", "Plac", "Expr"))))
```

you get:

```
> AnalysedData
  Participant Code Condition    DV Trial
1        Bill    1       Con 26.07     1
2        Bill    1      Expr 26.06     2
3        Bill    1      Plac 26.05     3
4       Harry    2       Con 26.09     1
5       Harry    2      Expr 26.04     3
6       Harry    2      Plac 26.65     2
7        Paul    1       Con 26.64     1
8        Paul    1      Expr 26.62     2
9        Paul    1      Plac 26.63     3
```

Comment: Thank you, I realised I had `Code` in the example and `Order` in the anticipated output. I have amended so that `Code` appears in both. Apologies for the confusion and thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
AnalysedData$Trial <- ifelse(AnalysedData$Condition == "Con", 1, 0)

index<-AnalysedData$Condition == "Plac"

AnalysedData$Trial[index]<-rep(2,sum(index))
```

Comment: Thank you but it resulted in: dput(AnalysedData)
structure(list(Participant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Bill", "Harry", "Paul"), class = "factor"), 
    Code = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), Condition = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Con", "Expr", 
    "Plac"), class = "factor"), DV = c(26.07, 26.06, 26.05, 26.09, 
    26.04, 26.65, 26.64, 26.62, 26.63), Trial = c(1, 0, 2, 1, 
    0, 2, 1, 0, 2)), .Names = c("Participant", "Code", "Condition", 
"DV", "Trial"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I am unsure if I have explained my question clearly as I am after AnalysedData$Trial <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3) that addresses Harry who completed the placebo condition second and experimental third, giving c(1, 3, 2). In contrast, Bill and Paul have c(1, 2, 3) for completing the experimental condition second and placebo third.